# Mutual followers postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

How can I find mutual followers? I am new to postgres and I am having a hard time constructing this.

```
followers

u_id     f_id
3        1
2        5
4        3
1        2
4        1
1        3
2        8
2        10
1        4
2        4
3        4
4        5
4        8
```

example of expected output:

```
u_id f_id
3    1
1    3
4    3
3    4
...
...
```

Comment: Do you really want a row for every mutual u/f combination? You already have two rows with a u_id of 3, imagine what would happen when thousands of users are all following each other. I'd construct it maybe as `u_id INTEGER, f_ids INTEGER[]`

Comment: @eurotrash I have the correct query, `SELECT f1.u_id, f2.u_id FROM followers f1 JOIN followers f2 ON f1.u_id = f2.f_id AND f2.u_id = f1.f_id`. Not sure how to do what you suggested and remove redundant data

Comment: try `SELECT f1.u_id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT f2.u_id ORDER BY f2.u_id) FROM` and the rest of your query, followed by `GROUP BY f1.u_id ORDER BY f1.u_id`, I think that should work.